# aws CodeDeploy error : Artifact [Source] exceeds max artifact size

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-code-deploy, aws-codepipeline

When I run the pipeline the deploy step fails.
When I click on the "details" link a popup appears and the error message :

> "Action execution failed 
>    Artifact [Source] exceeds max artifact size"

I have tried to google for the error message, searched stackoverflow, read about the limitations etc.

Any tips or advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CodePipeline has a limit of 512MB if you're deploying to Elastic Beanstalk, 1GB if your source artifact is from a `git repo`, and 2GB if your source artifact is an S3 bucket.

Perhaps you can find a way to reduce the size of your artifact by removing files that are not needed in production.